# awk - find exact string in column

Tags: awk

I would like to find specific string and combinations of string in one column. Could you help me please?

INPUT:

```
benign,likely_pathogenic
benign,likely_pathogenic
benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
risk_factor,uncertain_significance,likely_pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,benign
risk_factor,uncertain_significance,likely_pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,benign
risk_factor,benign,likely_benign,drug_response,not_provided,uncertain_significance,pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
pathogenic,not_provided,benign,likely_pathogenic,likely_benign,risk_factor
likely_benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
benign,likely_benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
benign,likely_pathogenic
uncertain_significance,likely_benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
benign,likely_pathogenic
conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity,_other,benign,pathogenic,likely_benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity,_other,benign,pathogenic,likely_benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
risk_factor,benign,likely_benign,drug_response,not_provided,uncertain_significance,pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
pathogenic,likely_pathogenic
uncertain_significance,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity,likely_benign
benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
pathogenic
```

OUTPUT:

```
benign,likely_pathogenic
benign,likely_pathogenic
risk_factor,uncertain_significance,likely_pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,benign
risk_factor,uncertain_significance,likely_pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,benign
risk_factor,benign,likely_benign,drug_response,not_provided,uncertain_significance,pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
pathogenic,not_provided,benign,likely_pathogenic,likely_benign,risk_factor
benign,likely_pathogenic
benign,likely_pathogenic
conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity,_other,benign,pathogenic,likely_benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity,_other,benign,pathogenic,likely_benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
pathogenic,likely_pathogenic
pathogenic
```

I would like to separate every column which contain pathogenic and likely_pathogenic. But part of string pathogenic is in conflicting_interpretations_of_**pathogenic**ity.
I tried

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{if($14=="pathogenic") print FILENAME,$0; else if($14=="likely_pathogenic") print FILENAME,$0}'
```

but it is for exact string in column

If I tried:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{if($14~"pathogenic") print FILENAME,$0}'
```

I get all rows with pathogenic, likely_pathogenic and conflicting_interpretations_of_**pathogenic**ity. In one row could be combination of conflicting... and pathogenic or likely_pathogenic.

Comment: Regarding `-F'\t' -v OFS="\t"` - why single quote one but double quote the other? Always use single quotes unless you **need** double quotes or no quotes. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, maybe:

```
awk '{
    split($0,a,/,/)                          # split NEEDED field on commas
    for(i in a)                              # check each part
        if(a[i]~/^(likely_)?pathogenic$/) {  # if matches this regex
            print                            # output
            break                            # no need for more matches
        }
}' file
```

Some output:

```
benign,likely_pathogenic
benign,likely_pathogenic
risk_factor,uncertain_significance,likely_pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,benign
...
```

Obviously you need to add `FS` etc. as in your sample code you were processing `NF==14`.

**Edit:**

I guess this would work too for the posted sample data:

```
$ awk '/(^|,)(likely_)?pathogenic(,|$)/' file
```

or for your assumed data:

```
$ awk '$14~/(^|,)(likely_)?pathogenic(,|$)/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

I would exploit GNU `AWK`'s [word boundary](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html) for this task as follows, let `file.txt` content be

```
benign,likely_pathogenic
benign,likely_pathogenic
benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
risk_factor,uncertain_significance,likely_pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,benign
risk_factor,uncertain_significance,likely_pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,benign
risk_factor,benign,likely_benign,drug_response,not_provided,uncertain_significance,pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
pathogenic,not_provided,benign,likely_pathogenic,likely_benign,risk_factor
likely_benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
benign,likely_benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
benign,likely_pathogenic
uncertain_significance,likely_benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
benign,likely_pathogenic
conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity,_other,benign,pathogenic,likely_benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity,_other,benign,pathogenic,likely_benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
risk_factor,benign,likely_benign,drug_response,not_provided,uncertain_significance,pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
pathogenic,likely_pathogenic
uncertain_significance,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity,likely_benign
benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
pathogenic
```

then

```
/pathogenic\y/{print}
```

gives output

```
benign,likely_pathogenic
benign,likely_pathogenic
risk_factor,uncertain_significance,likely_pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,benign
risk_factor,uncertain_significance,likely_pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,benign
risk_factor,benign,likely_benign,drug_response,not_provided,uncertain_significance,pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
pathogenic,not_provided,benign,likely_pathogenic,likely_benign,risk_factor
benign,likely_pathogenic
benign,likely_pathogenic
conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity,_other,benign,pathogenic,likely_benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity,_other,benign,pathogenic,likely_benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
risk_factor,benign,likely_benign,drug_response,not_provided,uncertain_significance,pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
pathogenic,likely_pathogenic
pathogenic
```

Explanation: word boundary (`\y`) is zero-length assertion, it can be placed before, after or before and after, first gives word starting with, second word ending with, third whole words. So `pathogen\y` mean words ending with `pathogen`. GNU `AWK` define word as sequence of one or more letters, digits or underscores. *Note:* output is slighty different from desired shown as it does 4th *risk_factor* line, but it is compliant with description as that line holds `,pathogenic,`

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

the best case (it's not complete) i could quickly get to without using word boundary regex :

> ```
> echo "${input….}" | 
>  
> mawk '$!(NF=NF)~ /pathogenic/' \
>          FS='[^,]*pathogenic[[:alpha:]][^,]*' OFS=
> ```

```
 1  benign,likely_pathogenic
 2  benign,likely_pathogenic
 3  risk_factor,uncertain_significance,likely_pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,benign
 4  risk_factor,uncertain_significance,likely_pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,benign
 5  risk_factor,benign,likely_benign,drug_response,not_provided,uncertain_significance,pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,
 6  pathogenic,not_provided,benign,likely_pathogenic,likely_benign,risk_factor
 7  benign,likely_pathogenic
 8  benign,likely_pathogenic
 9  ,_other,benign,pathogenic,likely_benign,
10  ,_other,benign,pathogenic,likely_benign,
11  risk_factor,benign,likely_benign,drug_response,not_provided,uncertain_significance,pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,
12  pathogenic,likely_pathogenic
13  pathogenic
```

it might be deleteing too much stuff around rows 9-10

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -E '(likely_)?pathogenic\b' file
$ sed -En '/(likely_)?pathogenic\b/p' file
$ awk '/(likely_)?pathogenic\y/' file

benign,likely_pathogenic
benign,likely_pathogenic
risk_factor,uncertain_significance,likely_pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,benign
risk_factor,uncertain_significance,likely_pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,benign
risk_factor,benign,likely_benign,drug_response,not_provided,uncertain_significance,pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
pathogenic,not_provided,benign,likely_pathogenic,likely_benign,risk_factor
benign,likely_pathogenic
benign,likely_pathogenic
conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity,_other,benign,pathogenic,likely_benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity,_other,benign,pathogenic,likely_benign,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
risk_factor,benign,likely_benign,drug_response,not_provided,uncertain_significance,pathogenic,uncertain_significance,_other,conflicting_interpretations_of_pathogenicity
pathogenic,likely_pathogenic
pathogenic
```